# Ubuntu 12.04 (server): Failed to load fallback graphics devices?

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, boot-failure

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 (server, x64) under ESXi 5.0 and it appears to be working fine, but when it boots I get the following message:

```
* Starting load fallback graphics devices        [fail]
```

Everything seems to be working fine but the error message is bothering me.  The server is headless (ie. running as a virtual machine).

Anybody know anything about this message? Can it be fixed?

(There appears to be another unanswered question the same as mine:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/101446/load-fallback-graphics-devices-problem)

Comment: Are you using vCenter or something similar? Somehow you should be able to access the console through ESX. It is quite possible that you need an extra driver for VMware's virtual hardware, which is causing this error. Remember that in case of trouble, the only reliable way to get into your server is through the console.

Comment: Oh, the server continues booting and I can access it via SSH or the ESXi console.  I just don't like seeing the error (and it concerns me).  I've also installed the latest VMware Tools (which includes all the drivers, etc)...

Comment: I've never bothered to further check the message other than checking through ESXi/vCenter console. Never had any problems myself with the message, but there may be others with more/other experience.

Answer (score 2):

Have almost the same problem. I am using desktop version and after some hack with lightdm i was unable to boot even to bash command prompt with the same error message in boot log. I removed lightdm and now i get command prompt back. Maybe this somehow helps you.